# Maven Detection of Old Setting Mechanism

Tags: maven

I'm experimenting with the `jgitver` maven plugin to aid in setting release versions for a project. Following the "manual" install [instructions](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin#activation-by-maven-core-extension), I added the requisite extensions.xml file to my `.mvn` folder in the root of my project.

The contents of the file are basic

```
<extensions xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/EXTENSIONS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/core-extensions-1.0.0.xsd">
    <extension>
        <groupId>fr.brouillard.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jgitver-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </extension>
</extensions>
```

However, when I run a simple `mvn validate` on the project I receive the following output

```
$ mvn validate
[INFO] Using jgitver configuration file: C:\development\code\microfrontends\mfgweb\events-tracking\event-data\.mvn\jgitver.config.xml
[INFO] Using jgitver-maven-plugin [1.9.0] (sha1: 410af24b23bf392ebb2810475800189c6d881817)
[INFO]     version '0.0.0-git_release_test-dirty-SNAPSHOT' computed in 3412 ms
[INFO]
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] jgitver has changed!
[WARNING]
[WARNING] it now requires the usage of maven core extensions (> 3.3.1) instead of standard plugin extensions.
[WARNING] The plugin must be now declared in a `.mvn/extensions.xml` file.
[WARNING]
[WARNING]     read https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin for further information
[WARNING]
[ERROR] detection of jgitver old setting mechanism: jgitver must now use maven core extensions only -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MavenExecutionException
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver-maven-plugin/issues/119) logged under the jgitver-maven-plugin project issue log which ties back to [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6765) in the maven project issue log.

According to the jgitver issue, this was resolved in maven 3.6.2. So I went back and downloaded version 3.6.3 and 3.6.1 and tried running `mvn validate` using each of thi=ose versions with the exact same result. I then cloned the jgitver-maven-plugin project and ran `mvn validate` on that project with the exact same result.

I am, by default, using maven version 3.8.6

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: F:\development\Apache\Maven\Latest
Java version: 17, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: F:\development\languages\Java\openJDK_17
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Any ideas on what might be going wrong?